# How I can use it to ensure anonymous ERC20 token transaction?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

guys.
I heard about ZK (zero knowledge) proof that has been released at Ethereum Byzantium hardfork.
Can you tell me please: How I can use it to ensure anonymous ERC20 token transaction.
Can I use it in Solidity-based Ethereum smart-contract yet or i need to wait full implementation?

Thank you for advance! :)

Comment: if you are looking for a tutorial SO in not the right place

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this cannot be done yet. The only progress made regarding ZK in Ethereum is verifying a transaction made on the Zcash blockchain. In other words yes you need to wait for a full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Zero Knowledge Proofs are quite possible in Ethereum now. Zokrates, Snarky, Aztec etc. support ZKP implementations based on ZKSnark standard. There will be on-chain verification in the Ethereum Smart Contract for every proof generated off-chain by the Prover. We can use the combination of ZK Snarks and Pedersen Commitments in Ethereum in this manner. Recently ING has attempted Bullet Proof model ZK Snarks with no trusted setup on Ethereum. As a simple approach you can use Circom and Snarkjs JavaScript libraries as npm modules for generating proofs and verify them on-chain using Smart Contracts and Random Oracles.

[Zokrates on Github](https://github.com/zokrates/zokrates)

[Semapore on Ethereum](https://github.com/kobigurk/semaphore)

[Aztec Prtocol](https://www.aztecprotocol.com/)

[Verifiable ZKP Compiler](https://github.com/kyroy/VerifiableStatementCompiler)